# Checkstyle: Results file not being generated. 

Tags: java, ant, checkstyle

I am running `checkstyle` in an ANT task:

```
<taskdef resource="checkstyletask.properties" classpath="checkstyle-5.5//checkstyle-5.5-all.jar"/> 
<checkstyle config="checkstyle-5.5/sun_checks.xml" failOnViolation="false">
  <fileset dir="src/net" includes="**/*.java"/>
</checkstyle>
```

Anyways, the `checkstyle` is certainly running; I'm seeing a trememndous amount of output at the console. However, I do not see a `checkstyle-results.xml` file as output.

Of course, I'm assuming this is a severe error, and that `checkstyle-results.xml` is ALWAYS produced when checkstyle runs, by default. Is that correct?  I believe that the results.xml file is required by Jenkins or Hudson CI plugins as well.

Comment: -1: it took me 2 seconds to find the answer by googling "checkstyle ant task" and clicking on the first result.

Comment: Yup - for some reason, the "nested elements" heading threw me off. In any case - your answer was right on.   Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html:

> This task supports the nested elements fileset, classpath,
>   formatter, and property.
>
> The parameters for the formatter element are:
>
> type
>
> The type of output to generate. The valid values are:
>
> ```
> plain - specifies the DefaultLogger
> xml - specifies the XMLLogger
> ```
>
> Defaults to "plain".  No
>
> toFile    The file to write output to. Defaults
>   to standard output. Note, there is no way to explicitly specify
>   standard output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the output in a formatter element; by default it goes to stdout.

http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html